Simple probability problem of pulling 2 colored balls from the basket
This problem is quite simple and was easy to get the correct answer, but when I tried to approach from other perspective, it confused me a little hard. It seems that I am mistaken about the definition of probability, but it is difficult to clearly point out where it is wrong.
Problem :

There are 2 white balls and 3 black balls in the basket. Starting from A, A and B pull the ball out of the pocket in turn. If the person who pulls out the second white ball wins, What is the probability that A will win?


The optimal approach should be something like this:
case 1 : A → B → A

◯, ⚫, ◯ : $\frac{2}{5} \times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{10}$
⚫, ◯, ◯ : $\frac{3}{5} \times \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{10}$

case 2 : A → B → A → B → A

◯, ⚫, ⚫, ⚫, ◯ : $\frac{2}{5} \times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} \times 1 = \frac{1}{10}$
⚫, ◯, ⚫, ⚫, ◯ : $\frac{3}{5} \times \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} \times 1 = \frac{1}{10}$
⚫, ⚫, ◯, ⚫, ◯ : $\frac{3}{5} \times \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} \times 1 = \frac{1}{10}$
⚫, ⚫, ⚫, ◯, ◯ : $\frac{3}{5} \times \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{1}{3} \times 1 \times 1 = \frac{1}{10}$

Answer : $\frac{1}{10} \times 6 = \frac{3}{5}$

Now this is where I got lost. Let's name each balls W1, W2, B1, B2, B3.
Number of A's winning cases :

◯, ⚫, ◯ : 3 Black balls, and 2 white balls so $3 \times 2 = 6$
⚫, ◯, ◯ : same logic, $6$.

This is pretty clear since you can count all possible cases like this.

W1, {B1~B3}, W2 : 3 cases
W2, {B1~B3}, W1 : 3 cases
{B1~B3}, W1, W2 : 3 cases
{B1~B3}, W2, W1 : 3 cases

Similarly,

◯, ⚫, ⚫, ⚫, ◯ : $2 \times 3! = 12$
⚫, ◯, ⚫, ⚫, ◯ : $12$
⚫, ⚫, ◯, ⚫, ◯ : $12$
⚫, ⚫, ⚫, ◯, ◯ : $12$

So I thought A's winning cases are $12 + 48 = 60$.
Number of B's winning cases :
case 1 : A → B

◯, ◯ : $2$. (W1, W2) and (W2, W1).

case 2 : A → B → A → B

◯, ⚫, ⚫, ◯ : $2 \times (3 \times 2) = 12$
⚫, ◯, ⚫, ◯ : $12$
⚫, ⚫, ◯, ◯ : $12$

So the number of B's winning cases are $2 + 36 = 38$.
Thus, number of games set should be 98, where A can only win 60 out of those. So the answer should be $\frac{60}{98}$? I wonder where are those missing 2 cases.

It's not clear how you're counting games in your second approach. But $12+48$ doesn't match up with $P(\textrm{case 1}) = \frac{2}{10}$ and $P(\textrm{case 2}) = \frac{4}{10}$.

@aschepler I've added more details, I think I'm missing fundamental concepts on definition of probability itself or I'm just counting wrong but I am not sure which

Your first approach is clear and accurate.  Note there are only $\frac {5!}{3!2!}=10$ orders the balls can be drawn in.    You can extend each of your Case 1 examples in two ways to give the $10$ orders if you imagine they don't stop after somebody wins.
I also find the second approach impossible to understand.

The original poster left a comment explaining their thinking.  So, I added an Addendum-1 to provide a solution based on the original poster's valid approach.

It is difficult to analyze the original poster's analysis.  So,  I will offer my own analysis, that uses a method similar to the method that the original poster had trouble with.
Consider the following tableau
A  B  A  B  A
-  -  -  -  -
w  b  w  b  b

In the above tableau, you can assume, without loss of generality, that all 5 balls will be drawn.  That is, continuing to draw, after the 2nd white ball is drawn, does not affect whether A or B drew the 2nd white ball.
In the above tableau, A has the 1st, 3rd, and 5th draw.  There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2} = 10~$ equally likely ways of distributing the white and black balls.  In the tableau, the third row shows a sample distribution which results in A winning.
The question is, how many of the $~10~$ distributions result in the 2nd white ball occurring in either the 3rd position, or the 5th position.

$\underline{\text{Case 1 : 2nd white ball in 3rd position}}$
Then, the first two balls must be white and black in some order, and the last two balls must both be black.  So, the enumeration here is
$$2 ~\text{ways}.$$
The following tableau illustrates the corresponding distributions:
w  b  w  b  b
b  w  w  b  b


$\underline{\text{Case 2 : 2nd white ball in 5th position}}$
There are $~4~$ different positions that the first white ball might appear in.  So, the enumeration here is
$$4 ~\text{ways}.$$
The following tableau illustrates the corresponding distributions:
w  b  b  b  w
b  w  b  b  w
b  b  w  b  w
b  b  b  w  w


$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$
$$\frac{2 + 4}{10}.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
In the posted question, when the original poster is enumerating the number of ways that A can win, the original poster evaluates (for example)
w  b  w  (b) (b)

as representing $~3 \times 2 = 6~$ ways.  I can't point out the analytical flaw here, because I don't understand what thinking let to the computation of $~3 \times 2.$

$\underline{\text{Addendum-1}}$
This section responds to the original poster's comment, following this answer.  The original poster indicated that they arrived at a different answer, when they (arbitrarily) construed all of the white balls to be distinct, and construed all of the black balls to be distinct.
This is certainly a valid (although not preferred) approach.
In this section, I use the original poster's approach to attack the problem, in two ways:
$~\underline{\text{The First Way}}$
The probability will be expressed as
$$\frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = 5! = 120,$$
since, with all of the balls distinct, there are $~5!~$ different ways of distributing the balls.  Now, all of the ways that A can win, with the balls considered distinct are enumerated, and then summed.
w  b  w  b  b
b  w  w  b  b

w  b  b  b  w
b  w  b  b  w
b  b  w  b  w
b  b  b  w  w

In all six of the above ways that A can win, you have to apply the scaling factor of $~2! \times 3! = 12,~$ since the white balls can be permuted in $~2!~$ ways, and the black balls can be permuted in $~3!~$ ways.
Therefore,
$$N = 6 \times 12 = 72 \implies \frac{N}{D} = \frac{72}{120} = \frac{3}{5}.$$
$~\underline{\text{The Second Way}}$
The flaw in your analysis is subtle.  Going back to your posted question, you indicated (for example) that
w  b  b  b  w 

represents $~2! \times 3! = 12~$ different (equally likely) cases.  This is correct.
However, in your posted question, you also indicated that
w  b  w

represents $~2! \times 3~$ different cases.  This is wrong:
You can construe the tableau immediately above as representing $~6~$ different cases.  However, in that event, each of these cases is twice as likely to occur as (for example) the case of
w  b  b  b  w 

In order to use your approach, you must enumerate all of the equally likely cases.
Since the
w  b  w

scenario actually represents
w  b  w  b  b

it actually represents $~2! \times 3! = 12~$ different cases.
This is the subtle flaw in your approach.

I thought the correct way of counting was to distinguish each balls first and then count. So, naming each balls {W1, W2, B1, B2, B3}, in the case of W B W, There are 6 cases of these: {W1, B1, W2}, {W1, B2, W2}, {W1, B3, W2}, {W2, B1, W1}, {W2, B2, W1}, {W2, B3, W1}. Rest followed the same thought process. And then the number of the games set becomes 98, while A winning 60 out of them.

@SinonOW See the Addendum-1 section that I have just added to the end of my answer.

The part that got me confused at first was why I had to count the arrangement of additional black balls in a game that was already over. I've thought about it myself, and my answer to that is probably in a perspective of absolute observer,  even if the game seems to have ended exactly the same, it is actually a different case from an absolute point of view if the arrangement of the balls in the basket changes(since I numbered each balls).

And second, the reason why I don't need to separate each balls is because it does not affect the results of the problems even if they are {W1, W2} or {W2, W1} and the same goes for other black balls too. Am I understanding right?

@SinonOW Yes, based on your recent comments, it does seem as if you are understanding correctly.  So, if you abandon the approach of counting cases, and instead compute the (separate) probability of such separate events as $~W ~: ~B ~: ~W,~$ you should get the same answer.  It is only when you try (instead) to count cases that you get the wrong answer: then the approach is flawed, because the cases are not all equally likely.
